# decoding getter array

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I have a Python program that uses web3py to send transactions to a Solidity contract.

```
def send_transaction(data, gas):
    nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address)
    gas_price = w3.eth.gas_price
    txn = {
        "nonce": nonce,
        "gas": gas,
        "gasPrice": gas_price,
        "to": CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        "value": 0,
        "data": data,
        "chainId": 43113,
    }
    signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, PRIVATE_KEY)
    tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    return tx_hash

def send_function(function_name, *args, gas):
    data = contract.encodeABI(fn_name=function_name, args=args)
    return send_transaction(data, gas=gas)
```

There is a function presenting an array of data.

```
 function showOdds() external view returns (uint16[32] memory _odds) {
        _odds = odds;
    }
```

If I send my Python program a getter function like showOdds() above, it just returns the tx hash or something, which is probably a bytes version of a hash of something (for example,
b'\xbc]>\x03\xfe,A\x9f\x05\xe1"\x85'V&\x1b\xb0s\xb5\x19\xca\xe7\x17\xc2,\xb7\xa0^\xe5\xc9\x8a\xad', but it changes each time I call it).

How can I amend what works--a way to execute transactions using web3py's "send_raw_transaction"--into a way to access getter functions?